# Concurrency - Getting the MongoDB generated ID of an object inserted via Java in a thread safe way

Tags: java, mongodb, concurrency, mongodb-java

What is the best method to get the Mongo generated ID of a document inserted via Java.

The Java process inserting the documents is multi-thread, meaning that we need some atomic way to insert and return the ID of the object.

Also, if we setup a unique index, in the event that the object is a duplicate, will an ID be returned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generate the ObjectId early, use it in the insert, and there will no need to have the database return it to you.
ObjectId doesn't use a shared sequence number to be unique, so it doesn't matter if you generate one before inserting or retrieve it after.

```
public ObjectId createThing() {
    ObjectId result = new ObjectId();
    BasicDBObject thingToInsert = new BasicDbObject();
    thingToInsert.put('_id', result);
    //set other fields here
    collection.insert(thingToInsert);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: There is no randomness in an ObjectId. It consists of a time part, a machine and process part, and an incremental sequence part.

Comment: nilskp that probably changed https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Comment: there's no guarantee that id will be unique and it's not a rare occurrence either

Comment: @CervEd do you have any evidence for this claim? ObjectIDs have a 5 byte random seed, and a 3 byte counter (with a random start). Two processes using a different random seed have a 1 in 1,099,511,627,776 (that's 1 in 1099 *billion*) chance of choosing the same seed, and the same seed would overflow the counter if ~16.7 million ObjectIDs were generated in 1 second. Two get a collision two threads would need the same seed and enough values generated to overcome the random start position of the counter.

If a process isn't trying to have a collision on purpose, it's pretty unlikely.

Comment: @SeanReilly, yes. Multiple times.

Comment: What 5 byte random seed do you refer to btw? All I can see looking at the Java driver is a 3 byte machine identifier (based on NIC) and a 2 byte "process identifier" (which appears to be the JVM name). I can't see anything in either that they are random. In the source it says `This does not have to be unique per class loader because NEXT_COUNTER will provide the uniqueness`, which is the 3 byte counter. I would suggest adding a try catch for duplicate key exception

Comment: @CervEd I'm referring to the official Mongodb documentation for ObjectId as mentioned above: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

All official MongoDB drivers implement ObjectId the same way. Is it possible that you're looking at very old code somehow?

The description of ObjectId implementation in your comment above is definitely not accurate — or at least not _complete_ — because 3 bytes + 2 bytes is 5 bytes, and ObjectIds are 12 bytes in size. 7 bytes are missing from this description.

Comment: @SeanReilly I was refering to the '5-byte random seed'.
Which in [Java 3.8](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/3.8.x/bson/src/main/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java)
uses the not random machine/process identifier.
It appears this changed in the feb release of Java driver [3.10](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/3.10.x/bson/src/main/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java)
If you're generating the ObjecId client side you need to handle duplicate key exceptions, regenerating the ObjectId and retrying.

Comment: @CervEd again, please provide _evidence_ for this claim.

Comment: In particular, I'm looking for evidence that generating the ObjectId early & client side rather than late & server side meaningfully results in more collisions, given the nature of the answer these comments are attached to..

Comment: @SeanReilly `|collision of db generated ids| = 0, |collision of driver generated ids| >= 0 → |collision db ids| <= |collision ids|`
Earlier I provided an example of collisions happening.
The scenario was similar to OP, multi-threaded concurrent writes using the Java 3.8.2 driver.
It was roughly a dozen ids out of a few thousand, whether that is meaningful or not is subjective.
Had I stored them as documents in their own collection I would've experienced unhandled runtime exceptions, application failure and lost data.

Comment: Found 3 more collisions, java 3.8.2

Comment: @CervEd that's not evidence. Evidence would be a description (preferably with a minimal, reproducible source code example) of a _method_ that allows someone else to successfully reproduce your claim.

This is important, because according to official docs (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/) with official drivers, the _driver_ is adding the `_id` field when it's not provided by the user, not the server: "If an inserted document omits the _id field, the MongoDB driver automatically generates an ObjectId for the _id field." The server only adds _id if a driver doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

native ObjectId's which are generated by Mongo are globally unique and can be safely used from the multi-threaded application.

generated ObjectId can be obtained from the DbObject under _id key.

If inserted document violates a unique index constraint - java driver may throw an exception, depending on a value of WriteConcern:

```
 http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html
```

If it's value is higher then NORMAL- exception will be thrown.

WriteConcern can be specified for every individual insert (or update) method, or globally by using DBCollection.setWriteConcern

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this. The question what about how do you go about getting this ID after you insert the object? Do you just look for the _id field (i.e. is it set by the insert method)? Also what happens when its an insert of a duplicate? Do you get the id of the original document inserted set in the document after you call insert?

Answer (score 1):

I retrieve the document with _id but when I get the data into my java class eg mobile, _id attribute which is of type ObjectID me I change it set the value of the document in mongodb.