# How to get a saved object / newly created object

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I usually manipulate object by creating them unique "codes". (So I create an object with the code "test" and fetch the object back using `objects.find({ code: "test" })`. But I find this weird and counter-productive.

I'd like to know if it's possible to simply create a new object, and get its saved object or simply its ObjectId back once saved?

That would be nice if we could do this:
objects.save({ name: "Test Object" });

And get `{ ObjectId: "47cc67093475061e3d95369d", name: "Test Object" }` in return.

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: What programming language / API are you using?

Comment: @Thilo: I'm using the MongoDB driver for Javascript.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860773/concurrency-getting-the-mongodb-generated-id-of-an-object-inserted-via-java-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
> var record = {hello:"goodbye"};
> db.test.save(record);
> record;
{ "hello" : "goodbye", "_id" : ObjectId("4f90c9106aee6e21b4e55c65") }
```

Comment: What?! This is amazing, so once an object is saved, it gets its own ObjectId?! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is an API to get the autogenerated id back from the database, and there  is also no real need:

If your "code" is really unique, you can use that as the object id.

```
 objects.save({ _id: "test" });
```

The `_id` field does not have to be of type ObjectId, it just has to be unique. If you already have some primary key type data, you do not have to use the autogenerated id. This way, you also save one index.

If you want to use a generated ObjectId, generate it yourself before you call save:

```
ObjectId id = new ObjectId();   
objects.save({ _id: id, something: 12345 });
```

Comment: What I wanted is to STOP using "code" and simply manipulate ObjectID. The main point of the question is: Is it possible to get the object back from the save call? Thanks!

Comment: The second part of your answers helped me getting an object back, thanks!